# Using SVN, what if a commit in a branch is not merged and committed to a TRUNK until later or if another person svn up, merge, and commit?

Tags: svn

If I work on a branch called "R08", and there is a main branch "TRUNK", and I commit to "R08", and then

1. don't commit the change to `TRUNK` ever, but my coworker `svn up` in the branch `R08` the next day, and then merge, and commit to `TRUNK`, will my commit get merged into `TRUNK` as well?
2. I don't merge and commit to TRUNK, because I might make some more change or use a different solution the next day, and I did (say if it is a different file), and commit to `R08`, and this time merge and commit to `TRUNK`, will both commits go to `TRUNK`?

Some examples I see are `TRUNK` plus one branch, but there is only 1 person working on the branch and 1 person working on `TRUNK`.  I wonder what happens when there are 5 people working on the branch, and 6 people working on `TRUNK` at the same time? (and some are the same people).

Please give an answer instead of giving a link to a manual.

Comment: A branch is a branch, and the number of people working on it doesn't change anything to how merging works. You'd better read that manual. It's pleasant to read and will teach you how to work correctly.

Comment: but it takes 2 users so that you don't merge and commit but another user svn up, commit, merge to TRUNK, and commit

Answer (score 1):

As other comment mentioned, number of people working on a branch/trunk has nothing to do with the behavior.  Merging is simply base on changes in two branches.  Whether it is someone else making the change or it is the same user making the change has nothing to do with the whole process.

1. It will (I assume the "my commit" you said is the change you done in R08, and is committed before your coworker do the merge, right)?
2. Your question is not clear: what is the meaning of "both commit"?

Here is a simplified way to tell you what merge will do:

B1 branch out from trunk

```
   r10  
----+--->    (trunk)
     \-->    (B1)
```

Someone commit change A to branch B1, at r15

```
   r10   r15
----+--->        (trunk)
     \----X->    (B1)
```

Some other changes done on trunk, and the someone update to latest turnk and preparing to merge B1 to trunk:

```
   r10   r15 r16 r17
----+---------Y---Z->  (trunk)
     \----X->          (B1)
```

When it try to merge B1 to trunk, it will find out the changes done in B1 from the point it is branched out till latest, which is change X done in r15, and apply the change in trunk:

```
   r10   r15 r16 r17     r18
----+---------Y---Z------X'-->    (trunk)
     \----X-------------/         (B1)
```

All logic has nothing to do who and how many people is working on each branch.

Answer (score 1):

To 1.:
Yes it will, if not excluded form merge.

To 2.:
This is more a question of organization. Normally thinks will commit to trunk when they are finished. So you have to clear in your team when to merge. But this is applies to all teams.
In the projects I worked it was never a real problem.